# Getting the position of my UIBarButtonItem in iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift

On App Start, I highlight one of my BarButtonItems. Since iOS11 I am not able to do this anymore because I need to initialise it on another way.

First my old ios 10 code. I saved my barButtonItemView after initialising it.

```
let item1 = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "iconProfile"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(pushSettings))
self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([item1], animated: true)
if let view = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.value(forKey: "view") as? UIView {
    barButtonItemView = view
}
```

Now I was able to access the position of barButtonItem just by using the frame

```
barButtonItemView.frame.topMiddle.x
```

With ios 11 the picture on my UIBarButtonItem gets smaller. I was reading that I have to resize them by using constraints. So now I initialise my UIBarButtons by using this function:

```
let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: imageName))
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 5, y: 7, width: 20, height: 20)

let button = UIButton()
button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 34)
button.addTarget(self, action: action, for: .touchUpInside)
button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 34).isActive = true

button.addSubview(imageView)

let barItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
return barItem
```

I set my rightBarButtonItem on the same way and try to get the view on the same way.

```
self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([item1], animated: true)
if let view = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.value(forKey: "view") as? UIView {
    barButtonItemView = view
}
```

But this time my barButtonItemView has the x and y values set to 0,0. Has anyone an idea how I can get the position of my BarButtonItem depending on my screen?

#### What I tried

The first solution I tried is to call layoutIfNeeded() before I try to get the frame again. This is not working as well as the x and y values are still 0,0.

Comment: You've already initialized your `UIBarButtonItem` with custom view. So why do u try to retrieve it again using `value(forKey: "view")`? just use the custom view that u passed

Answer (score 1):

First, if your `UIBarButtonItem` only needs to display an `UIImage`, you should use `[UIBarButtonItem initWithImage:style:target:action:]` instead of customView for more standard layout. And if you want to custom the size of `UIBarButtonItem`, you can resize the image.

Second, before iOS 10, UIBarButtonItem's view was added in the `UINavigationBar` directly, but after iOS 11, `UIBarButtonItem` was added in a `UIStackView`, and the stackView was added in the `UINavigationBar`, so if you get a (0, 0) from the customView's frame.origin, it means that the customView is layout at the (0, 0) origin in the stackView.

Third, the view of the `UIBarButtonItem` would not be initialized until the `UINavigationBar` was shown and your `UIBarButtonItem` was put in the bar, so you can not get the view when the `UIBarButtonItem` just be initialized. Maybe you can try to get the view and its frame in your viewController's `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidAppear:`.